# How to add a banner photo to GitHub Repository (in tags list)?

Tags: image, github, tags, banner

So I'm building an FPS game with Three.js.

But that's not what this is about.

I went on GitHub and searched other repositories with the tag <kbd>fps-game</kbd>, to see what makes them popular.

But some of them have a background photo (or "banner") on the Repository.

[image: Example photo 1]

However, mine doesn't:

[image: Example photo 2]

Obviously this is a custom picture.

How can I do the same thing with mine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. On GitHub.com, navigate to the main page of the repository.
2. Under your repository name, click  Settings. If you cannot see the
   "Settings" tab, select the  dropdown menu, then click Settings.
3. Under "Social preview," click Edit
4. To add a new image, click Upload an image....
5. To remove an image, click Remove image

**OR read the instrustions there:**

https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/customizing-your-repositorys-social-media-preview

Comment: Thanks! I already found it out some time ago. This is very helpful though, it will definitely help others in the future.